# Spring Boot 2 - Transforming a Mono to a rx.Observable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, rx-java, hystrix

I'm trying to use the HystrixObservableCommand with the Spring WebFlux WebClient and I wonder if there is a "clean" to transform a Mono to an rx.Observable. My initial code looks like this:

```
public Observable<Comment> getComment() {

    return webClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Comment.class)
            // stuff missing here :(.
}
```

Is there an easy to do this ?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use [RxJavaReactiveStreams](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaReactiveStreams), more specifically:

```
public Observable<Comment> getComment() {

    Mono<Comment> mono = webClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Comment.class);

    return RxReactiveStreams.toObservable(mono); // <-- convert any Publisher to RxJava 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Observable.fromFuture(webClient.get()
        .uri(url)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Comment.class).toFuture());
```